# SQL Select Unique Values Each Column

Tags: hiveql

I'm looking to select unique values from each column of a table and output the results into a single table. Take the following example table:

```
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
|col1  |col2           |col_3 |col_4          |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
|1     |"apples"       |A     |"red"          |
|2     |"bananas"      |A     |"red"          |
|3     |"apples"       |B     |"blue"         |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
```

the ideal output would be:

```
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
|col1  |col2           |col_3 |col_4          |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
|1     |"apples"       |A     |"red"          |
|2     |"bananas"      |B     |"blue"         |
|3     |               |      |               |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+
```

Thank you!

**Edit: My actual table has many more columns, so ideally the SQL query can be done via  a `SELECT *` as opposed to 4 individual select queries within the `FROM` statement.**